# Avoiding value Error into fsolve from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to solve a long block of equations from an EES implementation using the scipy.optimze.fsolve. But in this block of equations there are CoolProp calls that have a range of validation, and sometimes it yields ValueError. I want to know if there is a strategy to avoid ValueError and let fsolve try another guesses.

This is my code:

```
def block1(x):
    def cp_gas(Ti, Tj):
        return (1000/(Tj - Ti)*(x[6]*1.25 + x[1]*(0.45 *(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)
                -((Ti + 273.15)/1000)) + 1.67*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**2 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**2)/2
                - 1.27*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**3 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**3)/3 
                + 0.39*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**4 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**4)/4) 
                + x[2]*(1.79 *(((Tj + 273.15)/1000) - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)) 
                + 0.107*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**2 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**2)/2 
                + 0.586*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**3 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**3)/3 
                - 0.2*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**4 -((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**4)/4)
                + x[3]*(1.11*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000) - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)) 
                - 0.48*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**2 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**2)/2 
                + 0.96*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**3 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**3)/3 
                - 0.42*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**4 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**4)/4) 
                + x[4]*(0.88*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000) - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)) 
                - 0.0001*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**2 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**2)/2
                + 0.54*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**3 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**3)/3
                - 0.33*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**4 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**4)/4)
                + x[5]*(0.37*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000) - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000))
                + 1.05*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**2 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**2)/2
                - 0.77*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**3 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**3)/3
                + 0.21*(((Tj + 273.15)/1000)**4 - ((Ti + 273.15)/1000)**4)/4)))

    f = np.zeros(26)
    # x[24] = T_out_vent
    f[0] = x[0] - cp_gas(T0, Tgas5)
    f[1] = m_gas_teoria_conferindo*x[8] - x[9]*0.8 - x[7]
    f[2] = x[10] + x[8] - (x[7] + x[9]*0.8)
    f[3] = x[9] - x[8]*Z
    f[4] = x[12] + x[13] + x[14] + x[15] + x[16] + x[17] - x[11]
    f[5] = x[12] - M_CO2*x[8]/x[7]
    f[6] = x[13] - M_H2O*x[8]/x[7]
    f[7] = x[14] - M_N2*x[8]/x[7]
    f[8] = x[15] - M_O2*x[8]/x[7]
    f[9] = x[16] - M_SO2*x[8]/x[7]
    f[10] = x[17] - (M_Cz*x[8] - 0.8*x[9])/x[7]
    f[11] = x[18] - (e*a*((1-omega_ar) + 3.76*(1-omega_ar) + omega_ar)*(MM_ar_CBG)/(MM_CBG)*x[19])
    f[12] = x[1] - ((m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g_CO2+x[7]*x[12])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g)
    f[13] = x[2] - ((m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g_H2O+x[7]*x[13])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g) 
    f[14] = x[3] - ((m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g_N2+x[7]*x[14])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g)
    f[15] = x[4] - ((m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g_O2+x[7]*x[15])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g)
    f[16] = x[5] - (x[7]*x[16])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g) 
    f[17] = x[6] - (x[7]*x[17])/(x[7]*x[11]+(m_gas5-x[7])*FM_g)
    f[18] = x[20] - x[21]/rho_ar_in
    f[19] = (1/3600)*x[21] - (x[10]+x[18])
    f[20] = ((x[10]+x[18])*h_in_vent + x[22]) - (x[10] + x[18])*x[23]
    f[21] = x[23] - HAPropsSI('H', 'T', x[24] + 273.15, 'P', P_out_vent*1e3, 'W', omega_ar)/1e3
    f[22] = x[22] - (0.000012523*x[20] + 0.054570445)
    f[23] = x[25] - HAPropsSI('C', 'T', x[24] + 273.15, 'P', P_out_vent*1e3, 'W', omega_ar)/1e3
    f[24] = m_gas5 - (x[7]+x[19]+x[18])
    f[25] = eta_total - ((m_gas5*x[0]*(Tgas5-T0) - (x[10]+x[18])*x[25]*(x[24]-T0))
                       /(x[8]*PCI_RSU + x[19]*PCI_CBG))

    return f

x = fsolve(block1, np.ones(26))
```

The code yields ValueError depending on constant values that are previously defined.

**ValueError example:**

```
ValueError: The output for key (8) with value (-nan) is outside the range of validity: (0) to (0.94145) :: inputs were:"H","T",1.3025950731911414e+02,"P",2.0132500000000000e+05,"W",1.0890000000000000e-02
```

If anyone can help me I will be grateful.
Thank in advance

Comment: You could wrapping each call with [exception handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are running doesn't handle NaN values.

You can use try/except blocks to deal with it.
Or change the NaN values to a 0 (or any suitable number of your choice).

Here is a toy example to help you fix your code. You have to decide what should be the correct behavior and use one of the proposed strategies to deal with NaNs.

```
import bumpy as np

def f(x):
    if np.isnan(x):
        raise ValueError('NaN is not supported')
    return x**x


test_cases = [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 6, 7]

print('skip in case of error')
for x in test_cases:
    try:
        print(f(x))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
print()
print('fix X in case of NaN')
for x in test_cases:
    if np.isnan(x):
        x = 0
    print(f(x))
```

Output:

```
skip in case of error
1
4
27
256
46656
823543

fix X in case of NaN
1
4
27
256
1
46656
823543
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will be very helpful. I also know that the HAPropsSI from CoolProp admits values between (130, 630.15). There's other way to deal with it? There's a solver from scipy.optimize that I can explicit the boundarys? 

ValueError: The input for key (12) with value (873.15) is outside the range of validity: (130) to (623.15) :: inputs were:"H","T",8.7314999999999998e+02,"P",2.0132500000000000e+05,"W",1.0890000000000000e-02

Thank you again
best regards :)

Comment: Same approach, catch the errors, and deal with it accordingly. Or check in advance if the number you pass to each function. Without some background on what you are trying to accomplish and what data do you use, its hard to give a proper answer.

Comment: I think try and except solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help :)